# Debug or release APK build - Package Appears to be Invalid

Tags: java, android, kotlin, debugging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC7Tr.jpg)I was trying to create a Debug or release build for my Android Application in Android studio. The build was completed successfully but when I tried to install the apk file in my phone ,I was getting an error that "App Not Installed as package appears to be Invalid". I don't know why I'm getting this type of error. Anyone can fix this error.Help Me!! Thanks in advance

I tried so many methods such as removing cache. And referred some methods. I want a fix

Comment: Are you making debug apk or release apk?
This can happen when trying to install an app with the same package name as an already installed app. So also do cross verify this.

Comment: No, I have Already Uninstalled the previous app which I was tested in my mobile

Comment: Please mention which method you are using to build apk in android studio.

Comment: I tried both Build -> Build APk and Generate signed APK. Both ends in error

Comment: try using terminal adb uninstall `your.package.name` and then adb install `/path/to.apk`.

Comment: i tried this too but i shared the apk file with another phone(new device) . Even the app is not installing there

Comment: can you please build app's link & attach here. So that I can try to install it.

Comment: Dude. I have solved the issue. Thank you for your constant support

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by changing the build variant to release and tried

> Build -> Build Apk

or in terminal try,

`./gradlew assembleRelease`